# How to read/copy a (partially locked) log file, or at least the unlocked parts?

Tags: java, file, locking

I am working on a utility that zips up a number of files (for diagnostics purposes). At it's core, it uses the following function:

```
    private void write(ZipOutputStream zipStream, String entryPath, ByteSource content) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream contentStream = content.openStream()) {
        zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryPath));
        ByteStreams.copy(contentStream, zipStream);
        zipStream.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

But one of the files I want to read is a log file that another application runs and locks. Because that file is locked, I get an IO exception.

```
<ERROR>java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:257)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:112)
```

If I am willing to accept that I might get some garbage because of conflicts between my reads and the other application's writes, what is the best/easiest way to work around this? Is there a file reader that ignores locks or perhaps only reads all the unlocked sections only?

**Update** -- To clarify, I am looking to read a log file, or as much of it as possible. So, I could just start reading the file, wait until I get a block I can't read, catch the error, append a file end and go. Notepad++ and other programs can read files that are partially locked. I'm just looking for a way to do that without re-inventing the ByteStreams.copy function to create a "Copy as much as I can" function.

I should have perhaps asked "How to read all the unlocked parts of a log file" and I will update the title.

Comment: I would guess the process that locked the file would be a little miffed that the OS is letting some java programmer get around it.  That said, this guy claims to get around it with a straightforward StreamReader.   Maybe depends on what type of file lock. http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewD21B312F-242A-4038-9E9B-AE6AAB53DAE0.htm

Comment: @cogitoboy: The StreamReader example is C# and not Java.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer (which I don't like) is to create a method almost identical to ByteStreams.copy(), which I call "copyUntilLock" which catches any IOException, then it checks to see if the exception is a because another process has locked a portion of the file.

If that is the case, then simply stop writing and return the number of bytes so far. If its some other exception go ahead and throw it. (You could also write a note to the stream like "READING FAILED DUE TO LOCK").

Still looking for a better answer. Code included below.

```
   private static long copyUntilLock (InputStream from, OutputStream to) throws IOException {
        checkNotNull(from);
        checkNotNull(to);
        byte[] buf = createBuffer();
        long total = 0;
        try {
            while (true) {
                int r = from.read(buf);
                if (r == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                to.write(buf, 0, r);
                total += r;
            }
            return total;
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            if (iox.getMessage() != null && iox.getMessage().contains("another process has locked a portion of the file")) {
                return total;
            } else {
                throw iox;
            }
        }
    }
```